# CompletableFutureをどのようにショッピングサイトで使うか知りたい

Tags: java, java8, 非同期

今度Javaの案件にアサイン予定で、[CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)を使ったショッピングサイトを作る予定です。

結論から言うと、
**CompletableFutureをどのようにショッピングサイトで使うか知りたい**です。
CompletableFutureをショッピングサイトどの機能の部分に使うかということです。

背景として、
事前に勉強しています。
CompletableFuture自体があまり馴染みがなく、今並列処理や非同期処理、ノンブロッキング処理について勉強しています。
他の処理が行われている間も一方で処理をし続けられるメリットを活かし、多くの人が接続して処理するサイトやアプリにはいいのかなと思いました。Java8で新しく使えるようになり、Futureで対応しきれなかったところも柔軟に対応できる印象です。

例えば、映画館のチケット予約サイトもAくんが予約している間、Bくんは全く操作できないでは不便すぎるので、Aくんの予約処理を行いながら非同期でBくんの処理も行う。そこで並列処理が使われているのかなと思いました。（同じ席を更新する際は同期処理や排他処理にして重複しないようにして。）

ショッピングサイトに関しても、同時に大勢の方が接続でき、商品を選んで購入処理をする。これを同期処理だと不便なので、非同期処理にして。

そのようなところでCompletableFutureが使われているのかなと仮説を立てているのですが、有識者の方に実際のところどうなのかをお聞きしたいです。

**CompletableFutureをどのようにショッピングサイトで使うか**おわかりの方がいれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `CompletableFuture`で実装したタスクを実行するのはフレームワーク側になると思いますので、最初に気にすべきは(ショッピングサイト云々というよりは)「利用しようとしているフレームワークは何か」、次いで「そのフレームワークで`CompletableFuture`がどのようにサポートされているか」かな、と考えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Playフレームワークになります。
どのようにサポートされているかとは具体的にはどういったことなのでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば"CompletableFuture Play"といったキーワードで検索すると https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaAsync がヒットしますが、ここに "You must supply the HTTP execution context explicitly as an executor when using a Java CompletionStage inside an Action" とか "You can do this by creating a subclass of `play.libs.concurrent.CustomExecutionContext` with a reference to the custom dispatcher."といった説明と共に`CompletableFuture`(正確にはここでは`CompletionStage`)の利用サンプルコードがあるかと思います。私はPlay Frameworkについて詳しくありませんので正しい説明ができているか分かりませんが、このような形で、actionの戻り値として`CompletionStage<Result>`をフレームワークに渡すのがPlayがサポートしている形式だ、ということになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！調べてみます^ ^